# How to use lightgallery library on my website

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger, lightgallery

I accidentally found an image slideshow library (lightgallery) from a website, however I am not a good expert in javascript and open source. I want to use this slideshow library for my blogger, however I can't replace the images from the original source code.

Can someone help me with a piece of code to apply the above library on my blogger?

Sincerely thank!

Below is the source code I found:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1caUxD3gzAS_LKgugjnp73El6ITiWUKiP/view